# Why the scrolling is jumping back and forth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

While pressing down key I was expecting container to scroll by 210 pixels(size of row) each time. However it's scrolling some odd way: 218, 210, 428, 420, etc..

Here is how I scroll to next element:

```
$(".container").animate({scrollTop: $("#row" + currentRowIndex).offset().top});
```

Here is some related CSS:

```
.container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 90vh;
}

.row {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-size: 0;
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/souren/avLyhjw2/

Question: how to fix scrolling so that each time it will scroll one row, by still using "scroll to #ID" mechanism?

Comment: changing to: `$(".container").scrollTop($("#row" + currentRowIndex).offset().top-$("#row0").offset().top);` should work. I'm not sure why, first element seems to "move" 8 pixels sometimes!

Comment: This works, but can somebody explain me why it doesn't work the way I originally wrote?